# AngularJS - Unknown provider: $mdDialogProvider <- $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I am getting the following error message in the Chrome debugging tools console

> Unknown provider: $mdDialogProvider <- $mdDialog

Here is my controller

```
var studentApp = angular.module('StudentApp', []);

studentApp.controller('StudentController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', '$http', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $http) {

// Code here

}]);
```

Do I need to inject something at this line?

```
var studentApp = angular.module('StudentApp', []);
```

Comment: Did you inject and/or include angular material?

Comment: If I change this to var studentApp = angular.module('StudentApp', ['ngMaterial']);  I get Module 'ngMaterial' is not available

Comment: In that case you should look a this link and make sure that angular material is part of your project. https://github.com/angular/material

Comment: So I added Angular Material using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio but still no joy

Comment: Can you post the snippets where you inject the module and also where you include the scripts in the HTML? As stated above the issue points to an issue in one of those two places.

Comment: Thanks for all comments - it lead me to finding I had forgotten to render my bundles scripts in my razor code  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular-animate")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular-aria")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular-material") +1 for all comments Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to Load File Path

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"
```

you need to inject `ngMaterial` in your module creation. Such like that:

```
angular.module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
```